# The import org.springframework.web.servlet cannot be resolved

Tags: spring-mvc

I am learning SpringMVC, started a tutorial, I put all the jars in the library, but I got :

```
The import org.springframework.web.servlet cannot be resolved for :
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;
```

Comment: What's your spring release version? You have to import spring-webmvc.jar into your classpath. Have a look at [this](http://grepcode.com/search?query=ModelAndView)

Comment: Thanks lot, I just added it and the errors disappear.

Comment: glad to help. Please mark this as solved in the title or feel free to write up your own answer and accept it! And, welcome to SO!